# adding table values in javascript is giving me a result in the table cell of NaN

Tags: javascript

I am getting a result of NaN in my total table cell value. I am adding two total cells that are being calculated by each time the user enters in the quantity. I am trying to figure out and understand why I am getting this result. This is the code for the function that has the calculation in it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Cart </title>
<h1> My cart </h1>
<script type = "text/javascript">

function retr()
{
    var cke = document.cookie;
    var tot1 = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    var tot2 = document.getElementById("t2").value;

    if (cke.length>0) { 
         start = cke.indexOf("Circle=");
         if (start!= -1) {
             start = start + 7
             end = cke.indexOf("$", start);
             if (end == -1) end = cke.length;
             qu1 = cke.substring(start, end);
             document.getElementById("q1").value = qu1;
        }
    }

    if (cke.length>0) {
        start1 = cke.indexOf("$");
        if (start1!= -1) {
            start1 = start1 + 0
            end = cke.indexOf("e", start1);
            if (end == -1) end = cke.length;
            pr1 = cke.substring(start1, end);
            document.getElementById("p1").value = pr1;

        }
    }

    document.getElementById("t1").value = parseFloat(qu1) * parseFloat(pr1);

    if (cke.length>0) {
        start = cke.indexOf("Stickman=");
        if (start!= -1) {
            start = start + 9
            end = cke.indexOf("$", start);
            if (end == -1) end = cke.length;
            qu2 = cke.substring(start, end);
            document.getElementById("q2").value = qu2;
        }
    }

    if (cke.length>0) {
        start = cke.indexOf("$");
        if (start!= -1) {
            start = start + 54
            end = cke.indexOf("e", start);
            if (end == -1) end = cke.length;
            pr2 = cke.substring(start, end);
            document.getElementById("p2").value = pr2;
        }
    }

    alert(qu1);
    alert(pr1);
    alert(qu2);
    alert(pr2);
    alert(t2);
    document.getElementById("t2").value = parseFloat(qu2) * parseFloat(pr2);
    document.getElementById("tot").value = parseFloat(tot1) + parseFloat(tot2);
    document.getElementById("ret").value = cke;
}


</script>
</head>

<body onload = "retr()">
<table border = "1">
    <td>Circle </td>
    <td><input type = "text" size = "8" id = "q1" readonly = "readonly" /></td> 
    <td> <input type = "text" size = "8" id = "p1" readonly = "readonly" /> </td>
    <td> <input type = "text" size = "8" id ="t1">  </td>
    <tr> </tr>
    <td> Stickman </td>
    <td> <input type = "text" size = "8" id = "q2" readonly = "readonly" /></td>
    <td> <input type = "text" size = "8" id = "p2" readonly = "readonly" /> </td>
    <td> <input type = "text" size = "8" id = "t2" >  </td>
    <tr> </tr>
    <td colspan = "3">  TOTAL:</td>
    <td> <input type = "text" size = "8" id = "tot">  </td>
</table> 
<br /> <br />
<input type ="text" id = "ret" readonly = "readonly" />
<br / > <br />
<input type = "button" value = "Checkout">
<br /> <br />
<a href = "store.html" > Continue Shopping </a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to post an example at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Console.log these values at various stages so that you can see their values. Maybe one of them is undefined.

Comment: what kind of demo would you want to see? the table is set up as 3 rows and 4 columns. the second column represents the quantity, the 3rd is the price, and the last column is the total. I want to add the total of each item, but when I do, what is being displayed underneath for the grand total is NaN

Comment: i haven't learned about console.log. but the thing is, the total for each item is being displayed when i enter in a quantity and go to my view cart page(which is the page that i have posted now for), but the grand total returns NaN

Comment: if you use FireFox with the FireBug plugin or Safari with WebInspector (it's build in), you can print values to the error console by using console.log(value); in your js code.

Comment: or you could just use alert(value); to show the content of the value in a browser pop up.

Comment: for your problem, it would be best to see the content of document.cookie at the time your code is executed. So place an alert(document.cookie); somewhere in your code. But make sure not to post any sensitive data.

Comment: or do an alert(qu1); and alert(pr1);

Comment: i am able to see the content of the cookie. i have that tested on my main page where you can input the quantity. i will update my code and include that page for you to see

Comment: but actually when i do the alert(qu1) the value is defined with what the quantity was entered in. that goes the same for qu2, pr1, and pr2.

Comment: do you want the html of this page only, or my whole of both pages?

Comment: i just updated the code and now it's the whole code for my view cart page

Comment: actually, i just realized that the code i have there right now, none of the totals will show because it is unable to read the '$'. but even after i change the coding so that the '$' is not included, i still get NaN as a result for the grand total cell

Comment: it seem like how your extracting cookie value is causing the NaN, It would help if you post the cookie string as well

Comment: The HTML is a mess. The H1 is in the head, and the table's `td` are not in `tr`. You should definitely fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so assuming your cookie looks like this:

```
"Circle=123$456e; Stickman=123$456e"
```

I have fixed your code to run. Here is a working example:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/snies/kMzeS/12/)

You have several issues in your code, the main points:

1. You kept the "$" sign which is not a number therefore you got the
   NaN
2. You did not set the variables tot1 and tot2 after they were
   filled, or at least you did not provide default values.
3. While searching for the 2nd price you did not use the start1 position of the last "$" sign as a starting point. therefore you ended up at the wrong price.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the JavaScript value: [Not-a-Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_nan.asp) (NaN)? It sounds like some user entered value is generating a result that is basically an illegal number.